# PayPal PDT returning HTTP status 307

Tags: java, paypal

I am trying to fix PayPal PDT notification problem on a old Java 6 site running on Tomcat 6.

The configuration has Auto Return enabled with PDT enabled too so that is out of the picture.

As per [documentation from PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/payment-data-transfer) we redirect the user to PayPal through a form with all the variables needed. The user gets redirected as needed and can pay.
The payment goes through. The money rolls in the PayPal account as it should.

The problem occurs when PayPal is redirecting back to the site.
We receive the GET back from PayPal with the TX number as it should happen.

When we try to POST back to PayPal at https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr with parameters:

```
post.addParameter("cmd","_notify-synch");
post.addParameter("tx", transferId);
post.addParameter("at", PDT_TOKEN);
```

We SHOULD be getting a HTTP 200 with SUCCESS and with data about the payment or failure if the payment didn't work.

What we ACTUALLY get is a HTTP 307 redirect with header :

```
Location: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr/?IPN=true
```

Is this a problem on our side or PayPal has changed something that I don't know of (I didn't make this site and I it was given to me just to fix this issue.)

Answer (score 0):

I am using PHP with PayPal PDT and encounter the same 307 error. As a workaround, I find that using the http:// version will work.

Still looking for a solution for the https:// version though ...